# How i can give a role to user when its join the server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my code which is not working, Remember my bot is in **multiple servers**.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    role = member.guild.get_role(746380043344937081)
    await member.add_roles(role, reason=None)
```

This code is not working and I have enabled the correct intents.

Comment: What error are you getting, do you have the correct intents enabled? more info would make it easier to answer

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your setup, but here's the mistake:

You **can't** define your desired role by ID. On every server the ID of the role is different.

If the bot is on multiple servers, you have to go through the name search and the role with the name must exist on the server or on every server you want to grant the role after joining.

**Here is an example:**

```py
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Test")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    print(f"Assigned {role} to {member}!")
```

*Remember to also import the intents into your code, not just activate them. If you did this you will be fine.*

***What we did:***

- Get the role through the name, not ID.
- Imported `discord.utils.get` to be able to get the role by name.
- Printed out the result to see if it works.

Comment: You should also be passing `intents=intents` in the bot initialisation